# Let $G=S_4$. Show that $G$ is isomorphic to $J(G)$

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Let $G=S_4$. Show that $G$ is isomorphic to $J(G)$. Can anyone help me? I don't know that mean $J(G)$. Thanks.

Comment: What is $J(G)$?

Comment: The notation is not standard, but I would guess that $J(G)$ is the inner automorphism group of $G$. That would, at least, render the statement true.